# checkSelfPermission can not be resolved

Tags: android

I am considering Context of activity for asking the self(dynamic permission) in android. I am getting the error `checkSelfPermission can not be resolved` .

---

```
 package com.example.asus.provider;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class test  extends Activity {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(test.this , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        /// ToDo ....

     }
}
```

Comment: Try extending to AppCompatActivity instead of Activity

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved after adding

***public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);***

```
public class  test  extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  {

            /// ToDo ....
            Toast.makeText(test.this, "Permission (not) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

**EDIT:** Replace `ContextCompat` with `ActivityCompat`.

This is what I use:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Todo
    }
```

Comment: i tried to  extending AppCompatActivity instead of Activity. but still the same

Comment: EDIT: Replace ContextCompat with ActivityCompat. still the same